# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar las dos imágenes a la vez?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Con este código, ¿cómo puedo hacer que al clicar dos imágenes si y solo si son distintas, se muestren las dos unos segundos, se deshabilite el tablero, luego se vuelvan a ocultar en negro y finalmente se vuelvan a habilitar todas las imágenes?

Este es mi código: lo que hace es que si cliqueas una imagen, se muestra, pero al clicar otra, se pone en negro la que ya habías mostrado, sin mostrártelas las dos y luego ocultártelas.

```
var imagenAnterior = null;
var contador = 0;

var jugar = function () {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    
    list.forEach(function (imagen) {
        imagen.addEventListener('click', function () {
           
            if (imagen.style.filter !== 'opacity(25%)') {
                imagen.style.filter = 'none';
            }
            if (imagenAnterior === null) {
                imagenAnterior = Object.assign(imagen);
            }
            else {
                if (imagenAnterior.src !== imagen.src) {
                    imagen.style.filter = 'brightness(0)';
                    imagenAnterior.style.filter = 'brightness(0)';
                    imagenAnterior = null;
                }
            }
          
      
        });

    });

}
```

Comment: y dónde declaras la imagen anterior? pareciera que se asigna implícitamente a una variable global, pero eso es un error y si abres devTools debiese salir ahí. Antes de seguir depurando el código actual, sugiero que lo modifiques para encapsular dentro del handler cuál es la imagen anterior de la imagen actual

Comment: La declaro por fuera de la funcion, es una variable global

Comment: Antes la declaraba dentro de la misma funcion y me daba el mismi problema

Answer (score 2):

Tenes un par de erores de lógica. La idea debería ser así:

- Si la imágen se esta viendo, no hacemos nada.
- Si no hay una "imagen anterior" visible, la mostramos y guardamos su referencia.
- Si hay otra una "imagen anterior" visible, pero es distinta, esperamos 1 segundo y, ocultamos ambas y borramos la referencia guardada.
- Si hay otra imagen visible y son iguales, borramos la referencia (*y quedan vsibles*).

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var imagenAnterior = null;
var jugar = function() {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll('img');

  list.forEach(function(imagen) {
    imagen.addEventListener('click', function() {
       
      // La imagen se esta viendo?
      if (imagen.style.filter == 'none') return;

      // Mostramos la imagen
      imagen.style.filter = 'none';
      
      // No hay otra imagen visible?
      if (imagenAnterior === null) {
        imagenAnterior = Object.assign(imagen);
      } else if (imagenAnterior.src !== imagen.src) {
        // Mostramos ambas por 1s
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          imagen.style.filter = 'brightness(0)';
          imagenAnterior.style.filter = 'brightness(0)';
          imagenAnterior = null;
        }, 1000)
      } else {
        imagenAnterior = null;
      }
    });
  });
}
jugar();
```

```html
<img src="https://www.juegosdememoriagratis.com/img-menu/menu/16-juego-retratos-famosos.jpg" width="150" height="150" style="filter: brightness(0)" />

<img src="https://www.juegosdememoriagratis.com/img-menu/menu/16-memotest-frutas.jpg" width="150" height="150" style="filter: brightness(0)" />

<img src="https://www.juegosdememoriagratis.com/img-menu/menu/16-juego-retratos-famosos.jpg" width="150" height="150" style="filter: brightness(0)" />

<img src="https://www.juegosdememoriagratis.com/img-menu/menu/16-memotest-frutas.jpg" width="150" height="150" style="filter: brightness(0)" />
```